# What is the difference between ST_Union and ST_UnaryUnion?

Tags: postgis

Reading the PostGIS manual, it *appears* both St_Union and ST_UnaryUnion *should* dissolve boundaries of overlapping polygons. However, a simple test shows the following:

**Start data:**

[image: Test data]

```
insert into test (name, geom) values
('Top Left', st_geomfromtext('POLYGON((0 1, 0 3, 2 3, 2 1, 0 1))', 4326)),
('Bottom Right', st_geomfromtext('POLYGON((1 0, 1 2, 3 2, 3 0, 1 0))', 4326));
```

**ST_Union:**

[image: Union: one polygon]

```
create table test_union as select
st_union(geom) as geom
from test;
```

**ST_UnaryUnion**

[image: Unary Union: two polygons?]

```
create table test_unary as select
st_unaryunion(geom) as geom
from test;
```

What explains this confusing behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you read http://postgis.net/docs/ST_UnaryUnion.html you should notice that function accepts one geometry `geometry ST_UnaryUnion(geometry geom);` Your query returns two rows, each one being a union on a single polygon. Try this instead:

```
SELECT ST_AsText(
ST_UnaryUnion(
ST_Collect(
st_geomfromtext('POLYGON((0 1, 0 3, 2 3, 2 1, 0 1))', 4326),
st_geomfromtext('POLYGON((1 0, 1 2, 3 2, 3 0, 1 0))', 4326))));
```